# setting cookies between two different domains

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, nestjs

before asking this question I've searched a lot of related questions without any answer to what I want, I have a NextJS client app running on `http://localhost`, and a NestJS backend app running on a `islamabdelhakiim.xyz` domain in which I've built an api endpoint to handle the `/login` as follows "note the session & login creating"

```
    public async login(emp: CreateAuthDto, res?: Response, req?: Request): Promise<Employee> {
        const { email, password, rememberMe } = emp;
        const hashedPassword = EmployeesService.hash(password);

        const user = await this.employeesModel.findOne({ email, password: hashedPassword });
        if (!user) throw new NotFoundException("user not exists!");

        const userId = user._id;

        // set expiry
        let expiry: Date = rememberMe ? new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 : new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7;

        //create the session(
        const session = new this.sessinoModel<Session>({ expiry, userId });
        const saved = await session.save()
        const sessionId = saved._id.toString();
        
        //create the cookie
        res.cookie('session', sessionId, {
            expires: expiry,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
        });
        res.cookie('user', userId.toString(), {
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
        });
        res.status(200);
        return user;

    }
```

the thing is after many different attempts to set the cookies using my client app : `**http**://localhost` with the `secure` flag as false, the browser refused to create the cookies because of the **same origin policy.**

so, I've transformed my Nextjs app into `**https**://localhost` and the `secure` flag into true, **and then the server successfully created the cookies**, but with `islamabdelhakiim.xyz` for its domain, and despite having the cookies into the browser, the Next app couldn't read them because of the domain, and I noticed that if I manually changed the cookie's domain into **localhost** it can be read by my Next app,

so I've turned to my server-side and added `domain` attribute into the setCookie function as follows

```
//create the cookie
        res.cookie('session', sessionId, {
            expires: expiry,
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
            domain: "localhost"
        });
        res.cookie('user', userId.toString(), {
            sameSite: "none",
            secure: true,
            **domain: "localhost"**
        });
        res.status(200);
        return user;
```

but also the browser refused to set the cookies and threw an error next to the response's cookie header
[image]

I don't know what else to do, of course, there is a way for communication between two different domain websites, I'm trying to implement the session-cookie authentication pattern and I don't want to use any third-party package.

**Sorry for the long post**

Comment: Cookies are tied to a specific domain. It's not possible to set a cookie in a different domain, that would be a serious security problem.

Comment: Writer an interceptor to read for the cookies and set them manually. next-cookies can be helpful setting cookies on client side. If you're using nextjs Edge Function, then it would be rather easier to set cookie on server side. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain to me more, what is the logic behind the interceptor, do you mean a middleware to read the response's headers and set cookies on behalf of client app?, and what are Nextjs Edge functions and how to set cookies on server side?